# Hide button when clicked using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to develop a form where user submits:

1. Item
2. Quantity

The form also has 2 buttons:

ADD ITEM and REMOVE ITEM

The thing is upon ADD ITEM click, form appends new row(that works yay), but I want ADD ITEM button to go hidden as item gets added 
below is the html & jQuery code, i tried to get it hidden with. then but no luck lol

please advise

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
 var i = 1;

 $('#add-item').click(function() {  
  i++;  
  $('#table-fields')
  .append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input/></td><td><button>ADD</button></td><td><button id="'+i+'">REMOVE</button></td></tr>');
   });
 }
);


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="items-to-move">
  <table id="table-fields">
    <tr>
    <td><input/></td>
    <td><input/></td>
    <td><button type="button" id="add-item">ADD</button></td>
    <td><button id="remove-item">REMOVE</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The buttons which you add in javascript as well as your initial `Remove button` need a `type="button"` else it submits the form. That's why if I click any button but the first Add button everything disappears in your code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of work needed

**1st:** id should be unique .. use class instead

**2nd:** You'll need [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

**3rd:** create a click event for remove button and use `.closest('tr')` to catch the parent row

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  // add item click
  $(document).on('click','.add-item',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    i++;  
    $('#table-fields')
    .append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input/></td><td><button type="button" class="add-item">ADD</button></td><td><button type="button" class="remove-item">REMOVE</button></td></tr>');
  });

  // remove item click
  $(document).on('click','.remove-item',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="items-to-move">
  <table id="table-fields">
    <tr>
    <td><input/></td>
    <td><input/></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="add-item">ADD</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="remove-item">REMOVE</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> **Note:** This code just how to start .. but you still need some check's something like -if just one row then don't remove it- how many rows after add item or remove item -

No need to use `e.preventDefault();` while you use `type="button"` I used it here to double check

Comment: Thanks Mohammed for supplementing remove item thing!

Comment: You're totally welcome @ShamilMubarakshin .. But as I said its just a start .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 1):

To hide the button when it is clicked use

```
$(this).hide();
```

e.g.

```
$('#add-item').click(function() {   
    $(this).hide();
    i++;        
    $('#table-fields')
    .append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input/></td><td><button>ADD</button></td><td><button id="'+i+'">REMOVE</button></td></tr>');
  });
}
```

inside your click function.
But as pointed out by Ryan, you have a bigger problem when clicking add the second time.

Comment: right, thank you! I'd use above suggestions and tweak that with some more functionality

Answer (score 1):

when you add elements dinamically you should use something like this:

```
 $(document).on("click", "selector", function(){});
```

to make it works.

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
 var i = 1;

 $(document).on('click','.add-item',function() {  
  i++;  
        $(this).remove();
  $('#table-fields')
  .append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input/></td><td><button type="button" class="add-item">ADD</button></td><td><button  type="button" class="remove">REMOVE</button></td></tr>');
   });
 }
);
 $(document).on('click','.remove',function(e) {
  
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="items-to-move">
  <table id="table-fields">
    <tr>
    <td><input/></td>
    <td><input/></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="add-item">ADD</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="remove">REMOVE</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```